# How to use custom color in DrawString?

Tags: c#, drawstring

I want to use an RGB color instead of default color of C#, but I have no idea how.

```cs
e.Graphics.DrawString("Order Summary",
    new Font("Roboto", 15, FontStyle.Bold),
    Brushes.SteelBlue, new Point(350, 20));
```

Comment: Well, you're currently using `Brushes.SteelBlue`. Have you looked into how you might create a `Brush` for the color you want?

Comment: I just looked into it and got a solution thank you. I didn't know it was this easy.             
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(77, 183, 255)); 
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Order Summary", new Font("Roboto", 15, FontStyle.Bold), brush, new Point(350, 20));

Comment: I'd strongly advise you to "just look into it" *before* asking a question in future. It's worth asking yourself whether there was anything unclear in terms of where the color was coming from in the code you'd already got, and whether there was anything stopping you from taking the next step *without* someone else helping.

Comment: Do not forget to dispose fonts and brushes which did you create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("Order Summary", new Font("Roboto", 15, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100, 100)), new Point(350, 20));
```

You could also do something like this, if you don not want to specify the RGB values:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("Order Summary", new Font("Roboto", 15, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), new Point(350, 20));
```

Comment: You could upvote it too. :)

Comment: I tried to but it says I need to have 15 rep to upvote